# How can I line break in ecal echo? in bash script

Tags: for-loop, echo, eval

I need a help, i need line brake in my "eval echo".
It is a code for adding multiple additional ip in my server.

**code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo enter all ip
vi textfile.txt
echo gateway
read g
echo netmask
read n
echo how many ip do you need
read t

for ((u=1;; u++));

do
  read "d$u" || break;

done < textfile.txt

for i in `eval echo {1..$t}`

    do

eval "echo  DEVICE=eth0:$i\nIPADDR=\$d$i\nNETMASK=$n\nGATEWAY=$g\n" #  > "ifcfg-eth0:$i";

done
```

**output:**

```
DEVICE=eth0:1nIPADDR=192.168.0.2nNETMASK=255.255.255.0nGATEWAY=192.168.0.1n
```

**required output:**

```
DEVICE=eth0:1
IPADDR=192.168.0.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
```

Comment: I mean  line break